# Set.retainAll() empties set with custom classes

Tags: apex

Consider this minimal example:

```
class Test {
    private String val;
    public Test(String str) {
        this.val = str.toLowerCase();
    }
    public Boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceOf Test) {
            return val == ((Test) obj).val;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public Integer hashCode() {
        return val.hashCode();
    }
}

Set<Test> a = new Set<Test>();
a.add(new Test('abc'));

Set<Test> b = new Set<Test>();
b.add(new Test('abc'));

b.retainAll(a);
System.debug(b);
```

Set `b` is emptied. This is similar to existing question,  [Apex Set retainAll() with custom class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151525/apex-set-retainall-with-custom-class).

It appears like the `retainsAll` ignores `equals` and `hashCode` and instead works with references, because the snippet below will work as expected:

```
Test abc = new Test('abc');
Set<Test> a = new Set<Test>();
Set<Test> b = new Set<Test>();
a.add(abc);
b.add(abc);
b.retainAll(a);
System.debug(b);
```

If we create separate references, like `Test bar = new Test('abc')` and `Test foo = new Test('abc')`, `bar.equals(foo)`, `foo.equals(bar)` and `bar.hashCode() == foo.hashCode()`, but the set `b` is cleared.

Comment: Sometimes, the set is emptied if it is debugged before calling `retainAll`, but not emptied if it is debugged after calling `retainAll`.

Comment: This definitely looks like a bug in the core implementation. And the reason I say is because I wrote this piece of code (all versions in your post) in Java with a `HashSet` (and that the Apex API are based on Java interface) and could see the expected behavior. The original set did not change, i.e., it retained the value as expected.

Answer (score 0):

After much time wasting, Salesforce has decided to agree that this is a bug: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=the-result-of-set-sobject-retainall-set-sobject-are-inconsistent-between-apexcode-log-level-is-finest-and-it-is-finer-or-lower&Id=a1p3A000001HlAf